# Finding the curl - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I must be making a really daft mistake. If $\mathbf{F}=-y\mathbf{e}_x+x\mathbf{e}_y=r\mathbf{e}_{\phi}$ (in Cartesian and Cylindrical polars respectively):

$$\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=\begin{pmatrix}\partial/\partial x\\ \partial/\partial y\\\partial/\partial z\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}-y\\x\\0\end{pmatrix}=2\mathbf{e}_z$$

$$\nabla\times\mathbf{F}=\begin{pmatrix}\partial/\partial r\\ \tfrac1r\partial/\partial \phi\\\partial/\partial z\end{pmatrix}\times \begin{pmatrix}0\\r\\0\end{pmatrix}=\mathbf{e}_z$$

Where is the mistake?

Comment: are you sure that is how you calculate the curl in cylindrical coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Curls do not work the way you think they do for curvilinear coordinates. [See here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Formulae) for the actual formulae.